# How to capture stdout from another pts?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, stdout, pts

I have say two terminal sessions pts/10 and pts/11. In pts/10, I want to capture the stdout of any process that takes place in pts/11 and redirect it to a file. I know that the output can be redirected from pts/11 itself (using >/dev/pts/10), but I don't want to do that. As I said, I want to 'capture' whatever is being printed in the stdout by pts/11. Is there some utility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, you can do that, UNLESS, you start something on pts/11 (Either output redirect, or tee /dev/pts/10 or `script` command.)

If it had been possible, it could essentially be used in hacking/snooping.
Imagine getting passwords in case of `wget --user=someuser --password=plain_text_password` command run on the terminal pts/11 & captured by pts/10. (EDIT: Ok, that was stdin, not stdout.) But there may be serious security issue if it had been possible.

Comment: How about, if this is possible only if both the pts are controlled by the same user? Then it is not a security issue!